# Is this a bug in Devel::Cover code coverage?

Tags: perl, unit-testing, code-coverage

I have a sample code where I have `if` statement with `or` operator. In my test I check for:

```
0X
10
11
```

when I check the code coverage it shows 67% for the condition. Am I missing anything here or this is a bug in [Devel:Cover](http://search.cpan.org/~pjcj/Devel-Cover-1.23/lib/Devel/Cover.pm)

Here is my code:

```
use strict;
use diagnostics;
use warnings;
use Test::More tests => 3;


sub defined_values{
    my ($a,$b) = @_;

    if( not defined $a or not defined $b ){
        return 'not defined';
    }

    return 'defined';
}

test_defined_values_aNotDefined_returns_notDefined();
test_defined_values_bNotDefined_returns_notDefined();
test_defined_values_abDefined_returns_Defined();

sub test_defined_values_aNotDefined_returns_notDefined{
    is(defined_values(undef, 'b'), 'not defined', 'test_defined_values_aNotDefined_returns_notDefined');
}

sub test_defined_values_bNotDefined_returns_notDefined{
    is(defined_values('a', undef), 'not defined', 'test_defined_values_bNotDefined_returns_notDefined');    
}

sub test_defined_values_abDefined_returns_Defined{
    is(defined_values('a', 'b'), 'defined', 'test_defined_values_abDefined_returns_Defined');    
}
```

By the way, the actual subroutine is in the package, This is the sample code written in the test file.

I use Jenkins to run devel cover for code coverage. Below is the command that I use:

```
cd .\usr

if exist cover_db\NUL call cover -delete
if exist test_output\NUL rmdir /S /Q test_output
del /S t\*.tap

set HARNESS_PERL_SWITCHES=-MDevel::Cover
set PERL_TEST_HARNESS_DUMP_TAP=.\test_output
call prove -I .\lib --formatter=TAP::Formatter::Jenkins -l t

for /f "tokens=*" %%A in ('forfiles /S /P t /C "cmd /c if @isdir==TRUE echo @relpath"') do (
    set "file=%%~A"
    setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
    call prove -I .\lib --formatter=TAP::Formatter::Jenkins -l t!file:~1!
    endlocal
)

cover -report html
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: What about passing defined_values(undef, undef);  ?

Comment: @toolic My bad, the title is deceiving. I realized that the bug is not with Test::More, rather code coverage. @jmcneirney condition `undef undef ` is same as `undef defined ` because boolean operators are short-circuiting operators.

Comment: BTW Avoid using `$a` and `$b`. Those are magic globals, always declared, and used by `sort`. You will not get a warning from `strict` if you use them without declaring them.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you should report that as a bug in `Devel::Cover`.  If I recode your sub, I get 100%:

```
sub defined_values{
    my ($a,$b) = @_;

    if( defined $a and defined $b ){
        return 'defined';
    }
    return 'not defined';
}
```

[This issue may be related.](https://github.com/pjcj/Devel--Cover/pull/165)